# Active FTP Mode not Working in Linux

Tags: linux, ftp

I am new to Linux and I have my application running on windows for a while and for file Transfer stuff we use third party **sftp** and it has been running well both on Active and Passive mode.

Now i am migrating my app to support Linux OS, and i'm facing problem in FTP Active mode, where i can transfer files in Passive mode.

I tried through FTP command where i can transfer files in both mode and when it comes implementations it gives me the following error:

```
500 Invalid PORT Command.
```

and the before this error the ftp command looks like :

```
PORT 0,0,0,0,234,96
```

where for passive it works fine. 
Do it need to enable any firewall settings in linux, Please help me out.

Comment: Are you using FTP or SFTP? You seem to imply both above.

Comment: i'm implemented it using sftp jar.

Answer (score 0):

> PORT 0,0,0,0,234,96

The first four octets represent the IP address, which in this case, seems like is absent. So you either missed out declaring the client's IP address in the application or may be there is some other issue with the IP addresses. Try this link for more info: [FTP](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html#active)

Also check if its getting connected when you turn off the Linux firewall.

> /etc/init.d/iptables stop

Comment: Hey, i don't find the iptables under /etc/init.d, but i can able to find it out in /sbin/ and when i try to stop iptables it notifies me with an iptables stop as bad command, i tried installing iptables but it says, the system already have the upgraded version, what would i do now...

Comment: What is the Linux flavour you are using?

Comment: @Kallathiyan: You need to be a little more clear. Is it Ubuntu or Core debian? What version?